# Set root directory for project in Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012's Solution Explorer can be configured to display the actual files on disk (rather than just project files) simply by toggling the *Show All Files* button. Each project will display the files and folders located in the same folder as the project file itself.

Is there any way to change the root directory of what is displayed?

My cross-platform project is organized like this:

```
project/ide/vs2012/project.sln
project/ide/vs2012/project.vcxproj
project/src/*
```

I want Solution Explorer to show the files in my `src` directory, not my `vs2012` directory.

Comment: I created a feature request to add the ability to set a project root: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3641548-add-the-ability-to-set-a-project-s-root-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a symbolic link under the `vs2012` directory to point at my source code:

```
MKLINK /D src ..\src
```

Now Visual Studio sees the `src` folder underneath the project.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution crashes VS 2017 15.3.

Answer (score -1):

I think, if I understand correctly, you should open up the .sln file at the project's root in a notepad application and you'll find what you're looking for in there.

Comment: Why can't you just add project/src as a folder to your project in visual studio? Also, you can do something like create a single solution and then use multiple projects pointing at different directories if you have a proj file per project.

Comment: I have a cross-platform project and I would like to keep the IDE-specific files separate from the source code. Putting the VS project files at the root would muddle the file organization.